# Access Variable in JS Array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
 var object =   ["{
 "a": "foo",
 "b": "bar",
 "c": "baz"
}
"]
```

I am interested in getting value a, but everything I have tried comes up undefined.  I have tried object.a, object[0].a and object[a], I know it's something silly I am simply forgetting.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there really a string in that array?

Comment: if so use `JSON.parse(object[0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var object =   ['{  "a": "foo",  "b": "bar",  "c": "baz" }'];
console.log(JSON.parse(object[0]).a);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly it

Answer (score 1):

your array should look like this

```
var object =   [{
 "a": "foo",
 "b": "bar",
 "c": "baz"
}];
```

remove the double quotes so that you can access the object inside the array or else you can use the JSON.parse() just like @Daniel did